# Pulling a project from GitHub with EGit

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I've setup a private GitHub account to make it easier for me to work on the same project on both my desktop and my laptop when I'm not at home. The project was originally on my laptop, so I configured EGit to push and commit to my private repo. That worked successfully, and now I can see my project when I log onto GitHub. I'm now trying to pull that project onto my desktop. I did the same configurations , and in the Git Repository View within Eclipse I can see Remotes->origin-> the Push/Fetch streams. I tried to fetch, and that placed an origin/master branch under git\branches\Remote Tracking. But I can't seem to do anything with it.

I'm not sure what to do next, or if I made a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Now just right click it and `Create branch...`. This will make a local branch that will track this remote branch. When you push Eclipse should automatically configure everything so that `origin/master` will get updated.
Check out the local branch to start working.

**UPDATE:**
To import the project from working copy select the following:

[image]

If you have checked in your configuration files (`.project`, `.classpath` etc) you will get a list of all available projects in the repo to import to workspace. If not you will need to import them manually.

Comment: OP will also need to import projects from the Git Repo View to the Java Package Explorer (or similar for another language).

Comment: Ok, I've created a local branch called master and it's checked out. How do I go about Importing the project from Git Repo View?